# jQuery, find by tag name and class that starts with

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to find elements using both tag-name and class that starts with. I'm aware that you can do something like:

```
$(this).find(tag-name.full-class-name)
```

But how to use the starts-with (^=) in such a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think this is what you are looking for

```
$("div[class^='apple-'])
```

it will show classes which start with "apple-"

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[jQuery Starts with Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** to find tag element with start with class

```
$('tagName[class^="startWith"]');
```

Example - find `div` with class start with `apple`

```
$('div[class^="apple"]');
```

here you can search any attribute of the selected tag like `id`, `value` etc.